# laravel 4 upload a file

Tags: php, upload, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to make a form to upload a file, an excel file,
this is my html

```
<h2>Agregar Torneo</h2>
{{Form::open('admin/addtorneo', 'POST',array('files' => 'true', 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data"))}}

    {{Form::label('cvs', 'Archivo:')}}

    {{Form::file('cvs')}}

    {{Form::submit('Subir')}}

{{Form::close()}}
```

and the php

```
    $file = Input::file('cvs');

    $destinationPath = 'uploads/'.Str::random(5);

    $filename = Input::file('cvs.name');

    $uploadSuccess = Input::file('cvs')->move($destinationPath, $filename);

    $new = new Torneo;

    $new->nombre = $filename;
    $new->dir = $destinationPath;

    $new->save();

    return "Torneo agregado <br> <a href='../admin'>Volver</a>";
```

but I keep getting

```
Call to a member function move() on a non-object
```

I tried using $file->getClientOriginalName() instead of Input::file('cvs.name') but I get Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object, It seems to me that the form isn't right and it ain't reciving the file correctly

Comment: Looks like $filename isn't being generated. Change $filename to something like  'testname' (without it being a variable) and see if that fixes the issue.  Essentially it'll look like $filename = 'test'; if that does work, then change filename to this : $filename = $file['name'];

Comment: I keep getting Call to a member function move() on a non-object :/

Comment: when you view the form in html, what do you see? perhaps you're not setting a 'name' just the id.

Answer (score 0):

Just call Input::file('cvs') one time, the second time it becomes null object.

example :

```
$file = Input::file('cvs');
$destinationPath = 'uploads/'.Str::random(5);
$file->move($destinationPath);
```

It works.